# Exception "jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" while inserting into oracle database using jsp

Tags: oracle, jsp, exception, jdbc, insert

I used simple JSP code to insert 5 fields into my oracle 10g database.
And on submitting form I receive an exception "jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver".
I am unable to understand what is the problem.
please help me out.
My code is as follows:

signup.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Sign up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="align.css">
<script language="javascript">
function validation(Form_obj)
{
    if(Form_obj.fnametxt.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please, fill up the first name!!!");

        Form_obj.fnametxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Form_obj.lnametxt.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please, fill up the last name!!!");

        Form_obj.lnametxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Form_obj.usrnametxt.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please, fill up the user name!!!");

        Form_obj.usrnametxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Form_obj.pswdtxt.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please, fill up the password name!!!");

        Form_obj.pswdtxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Form_obj.phonetxt.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please, fill up the phone number!!!");

        Form_obj.phonetxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<a href="index.html"><h1>Jobs Portal</h1></a>
<div id="sign">Sign up</div>
<center>
<form id="form" action="signup.jsp" method="post" name="signform" onSubmit="return     validation(this)">

<table border="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Fill your details</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fnametxt"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="lnametxt"></td></tr>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="usrnametxt"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pswdtxt"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile no.</td><td><input type="text" name="phonetxt"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="signbt" value="Sign up" >                                 </td></tr>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

signup.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%

try
{
    ResultSet rs=null;
            Class.forName("jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:jobsportal","abdus","jbaat");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String fname=request.getParameter("fnametxt");
    String lname=request.getParameter("lnametxt");
    String usrname=request.getParameter("usrnametxt");
    String pswd=request.getParameter("pswdtxt");
    String phone=request.getParameter("phonetxt");
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into jobs(fname,lname,username,password,phone)     values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+usrname+"','"+pswd+"','"+phone+"'");
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from jobs");
%>
<html>
<head><title>Sign up Successful</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
Your details</br>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Phone number</th>
</tr>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString("fname")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("lname")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("username")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("password")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("phone")%></td>
</tr>
<% rs.close();
}}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    out.println(e.getMessage());
} %>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception. And don't use JSP to execute Java code. Use servlets instead.

Comment: Don't use the ODBC brigde. It's deprecated, buggy and slow (and never was intended to be used in a production environemt). Use the real Oracl JDBC driver (which has the added benefit, that you don't need an Oracle client installed). For more details see the Oracle manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

You're using the JDBC/ODBC driver to connect to an Oracle database. And you used the wrong class name to load it. The correct class name is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`.

The JDBC/ODBC driver is an old, obsolete driver, that has been created years ago when databases didn't have native JDBC drivers yet. If your database is Oracle, use the Oracle JDBC driver, and not the JDBC/ODBC driver. You'll have to use a different URL, described in the Oracle driver's documentation.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I always thought this had to be added just as any other driver. From where comes the ClassNotFoundException that the OP seem to get, then? Edit: found: the class name is in fact sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Comment: On using this class name I am getting error in my connection statement i.e. Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:jobsportal","abdus","jbaat"); Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

Comment: @AbdusSamad: don't post stack traces in comments. Edit your question instead (and post the relevant part and error message rather than the "noise" from the JSP/servlet engine)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your driver name.If an oracle driver is used,you have to specify if it is a oracle thin driver or oci or kprb. For instance,

#### For Oracle:

Jdbc Driver Name="`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`" (if you have it on your system)

Url format="`jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName`"

#### For Odbc:

Odbc bridge="`sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`"

Url format="`jdbc:odbc:dsn_name`"